# How to make class instances not look like '<__main__.Animal at 0x1f053e6abc8>

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, instantiation

Let's say I have a list of class instances, and when I call it in Python it looks like this:

```
[<__main__.Animal at 0x1f053e6abc8>,
 <__main__.Animal at 0x1f049e3f848>,
 <__main__.Animal at 0x1f0532e8d08>,
 <__main__.Animal at 0x1f053e6a1c8>]
```

Is there something I could add to the code inside the classes to make them instead look like this below?

```
[Lion,
 Gorilla,
 Tiger,
 Baboon]
```

Comment: Can you share your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `__repr__` method for your class. It should return a string. If, for example your class has a "name" attribute, you can just:

`def __repr__(self): return self.name`